# install intl mamp php 5.5.3

Tags: php, intl

I am using MAMP on a MAC and try to install the extension INTL 
when I do phpinfo it says that I am using version 5.5.3

I tried a lot of thing 
This for example

```
~ ****l$ sudo port install php55-intl
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for php55-intl
--->  Cleaning php55-intl
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

but when I refresh the phpinfo still no intl extension install
I even added this line extension=intl.so in tht php.ini

Let me know if you have any idea 
Thanks

Comment: Check for exact location of php.ini files both from browser and CLI. Also if you're using the composer - it will use the native PHP which is a bit more complicated to overpass so drop a bit more hints.